# Keras uses GPU for first 2 epochs, then stops using it

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, gpu

I prepare the dataset and save it as as hdf5 file. I have a custom data generator that subclasses Sequence from keras and generates batches from the hdf5 file.

Now, when I model.fit_generator using the train generator, the model uses the GPU and trains fast for the first 2 epochs (GPU memory is full and GPU volatile usage fluctuates nicely around 50%). However, after the 3rd epoch, GPU volatile usage is 0% and the epoch takes 20x as long.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try configuring GPU as given in this post https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu

Here is how i have done in my program

```py
print("Runnning Jupyter Notebook using python version: {}".format(python_version()))
print("Running tensorflow version: {}".format(tf.keras.__version__))
print("Running tensorflow.keras version: {}".format(tf.__version__))
print("Running keras version: {}".format(keras.__version__))
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  # Restrict TensorFlow to only allocate 2GB of memory on the first GPU
  try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(
        gpus[0],
        [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=2048)])
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Virtual devices must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)
```

Here is the output of above command:

```
Runnning Jupyter Notebook using python version: 3.7.7
Running tensorflow version: 2.2.4-tf
Running tensorflow.keras version: 2.1.0
Running keras version: 2.3.1
Num GPUs Available:  1
1 Physical GPUs, 1 Logical GPUs
```

Value might differ, `memory_limit=2048` is the amount of memory allocated to GPU device.

To confirm allocation please use `nvidia-smi`, if you run with this config keras won't increase memory usage. As you told that after 2 epochs it is very slow, can you tell further does kernel dies, system hangs or restarts? Issues without config I have faced, is system just hangs. If you are running on ubuntu 18.04 LTS please use  `System Monitor`(visually tells how many cores are being used, periodic contants increase means something is wrong) tool before executing all cells in notebook, once you start check `Resources Tab in System Monitor`.

Do:

- A fresh run
- Or Restart & Run All

Suspected Issue: [How to prevent tensorflow from allocating the totality of a GPU memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

**Same Error Here!!**

Because when you install tensorflow-gpu along nivida tool kit it provide a limited amount of GPU memory (Here in my case 2GB) .Due to leak of memory it release GPU finally and turn to use CPU .

if you want to avoid such condition  Use Google Colab which provide about 36.7GB GPU memory.

Comment: switching to collab is not an efficient solution, you still should be able to utilize local memory if available. What if colab goes full premium tomorrow?